# AMPL Network Flow Problems

Tags: network-programming, ampl

Is there a way solve network flow problem without having arc indices ? I have the below Set Branch: From_Bus To_Bus Branch_A Branch_B

Can I link the branch number with from and to buses without creating a cross set and manually entering all (From_Bus, To_Bus) in this format.

I have tried to define Branch_A in following way:

set Branch_A{Branch};

Then in constraints 1 {k in Branch}
Branch_A[From_Bus[k],To_Bus[k]]

Answer (score 0):

I do this like

```
set BUS;
set BRANCH within {1..4000} cross BUS cross BUS;
```

and then define the parameter of the branch as

```
param branch_r       {BRANCH};
param branch_x       {BRANCH};
```

I think this way you can manually set your branch set without node-arc matrix